# My aplication crash when I present my UITableViewController in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

This is my UITableViewController

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellId: String = "Cell"

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellId, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    let data: NSManagedObject = list[indexPath.row] as! NSManagedObject

    let nom = data.valueForKey("nom") as! String
    let temps = data.valueForKey("temps") as! String

    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(nom)".uppercaseString
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "à fait : \(temps)"
    cell.detailTextLabel?.font = cell.detailTextLabel?.font.fontWithSize(15.5)

    return cell
}
```

And this my action who present my UITableViewController

```
func seeAllScore(){
--------- when I put it in comment My App Work Correctly

    let tableView = AllScoreViewController()
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: tableView)
    self.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)

--------- when I put it in comment My App Crash

let vc:AllScoreViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AllScore") as! AllScoreViewController
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

this is my output

```
2016-02-14 23:01:39.350 WhereIsCage[42787:16030964] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3512.30.14/UITableView.m:6564
2016-02-14 23:01:39.358 WhereIsCage[42787:16030964] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
*** First throw call stack:
```

the goal is to have a UINavigationBar my UITableViewCotroler

Comment: Did you create the table view in code, a storyboard, an XIB? How have you defined the cell?

Comment: Check the table view content mode in IB. What does it say?

Comment: I create my table view in story board and i configured this in code

Comment: Which view controller in your storyboard are you presenting `All Score View Controller` from?  Is it from a view controller that is already in a navigation controller? `View Controller`?

Comment: No is `Find Cage Controller`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you have defined your table view controller in a storyboard but that you're instantiating it directly with `let tableView = AllScoreViewController()`.

Instead of doing that you should be loading it from the storyboard. It looks like you have also tried that (I'm unclear on the success of that test)...

Your current instantiation creates a table view but has no knowledge of registered cells, hence you get an error.

Comment: The storyboard is fine probably, the problem is that you aren't loading from the storyboard, so the cell you created in the storyboard doesn't exist at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

When you say this

```
let tableView = AllScoreViewController()
```

You are just creating a new view controller instance with no connection to the storyboard.  This means there is no information on the prototype cells and the reuse identifier isn't registered.

I understand that what you are actually trying to achieve is for your table view to be embedded in a navigation controller.  To do this:

1. Select your table view scene in Interface Building
2. From the "Editor" menu, select "Embed in->Navigation Controller"
3. Select the new navigation controller scene and give it a Storyboard ID (such as navController) in the Identity Inspector
4. Now you can instantiate your navigation controller with the tableview controller in it from your storyboard:

   ```
   let navvc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("navController") as! UINavigationController
   // If you want to access the AllScoreViewController
   let scoreVC=navvc.topViewController as! AllScoreViewController
   self.presentViewController(navvc, animated: true, completion: nil)
   ```

Comment: Hello thanx for your answer but i try this and i have this out put 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller <WhereIsCage.FindCageViewController: 0x7f93717de270>.'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: double check your code.  That says that you are presenting a view controller that has already been presented, so either you are presenting twice or your are presenting the wrong vc variable, but since your root view controller is already in a navigation controller you are probably going about things the wrong way.  You should probably have segues defined between your view controllers in your storyboard and then you can just use `performSegueWithIdentifier`